# How can I delete the Cappuccino Xcode Extension?

Tags: xcode, cappuccino

I installed an Xcode template for Cappuccino. I would like to delete it, but I am not sure how?

Comment: Damn, it's called "Xcode", not "XCode".

Comment: Sorry broseph, edited to be "Xcode" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find the templates somewhere in `/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/...`, I think. Once you find the files, just delete them, and everything should be fine.